# How to concat Pandas DataFrames based on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called 'records':

```
Name    Method   Path    January
Name1    Plane  LA-NY         20
Name2      Car  NY-LA         30
```

I want to append new records to it while usnig Name, Method, and Path together as a "key". For instance if I have dataframe 'to_add':

```
Name    Method   Path    February
Name1     Boat  LA-NY          20
Name2      Car  NY-LA          30
```

and combined it with 'records' I should get this (I am trying to get it to sort on Path first, then Name, and finally Method):

```
Name    Method   Path    January   February
Name1    Plane  LA-NY         20         20
Name1     Boat  LA-NY        Nan         30
Name2      Car  NY-LA         30         30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use pd.merge():

```
pd.merge(left=records, right=to_add, how='outer', on=['Name', 'Method', 'Path'])
```